# Java JAR not recognizing cmd line args

Tags: java, command-line, executable-jar

I have created a JAR file that takes in 3 arguments and returns a string but my code does not seem to recognize the arguments values even when they are correct.

I assign the arguments:

```
if (args.length > 1)
 {
    raftcode = args[0];
    Selection =args[1];
    Option = args[2];
    System.out.println("Getting arguments");

 }
```

I have checked the values they are correct but program never enters the if statement

```
if (Selection == "Sightings")
{  
            //Get sightings text
}

else if (Selection == "Captures")
{
            //Get captures text
}

else if (Selection == "Myrafts")
{
            //Get my rafts text

}
else if (Selection == "Other")
 {
            // Get other text

}
```

If I run the code without the args it returns the string using the default test variables and  I can output the argument values.

Any advice on what is wrong would be great :)

Comment: Compare string values with String's `equals` method, not with `==`.

Comment: Using `==` is bad for anything other than primitives (and is also bad for `float` and `double`, but for a different reason).  What do you think `("String" == "String")` resolves to?   If you aren't sure, try it!

EDIT: bad example, see below.

Comment: @Shrike That's not a good example as it does work (resolves to `true`) as compile-time string constants are [intern'd](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `.equals` rather than `==` as below

```
if ("Sightings".equals(Selection))
{  
        //Get sightings text
}
```

Comment: Or, even safer: 'if ("Sightings".equals(Selection))' to avoid potential null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Thanks works perfect now! Did not even think it was the == issue will not use that again :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said you should be comparing strings with `.equals` not `==`. Strings can be compared with `==` if you use `String.intern` everywhere but this is still risky as it will fail if you forget so much as a single instance.

If you are using command line parameters extensively have a look as [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)